Concerned About Indemification Clause
looking to accept a new contract to work on a software development  project, but I'm concerned about this Indemnification Clause:

“Contractor agrees to indemnify, defend, and hold harmless Company
from and against any and all claims, damages, losses, liabilities,
costs, and expenses (including reasonable attorneys' fees) arising out
of or in connection with a third party claim, action, or proceeding,
based directly or indirectly on any breach of its warranties contained
herein or arising from or relation to its performance under this
agreement.”

My Employer said that this means:

“ In the event of a lawsuit resulting from the creation or
implementation of this project, that you would be on the side of
Company — that you would not blame Company if anything went wrong..."

But From what I can tell, I’m not sure if this is really the case, the clause seems to say that  I need to pay for  any claims  damages losses liabilities cost and expenses including attorney fees  that come from our any connection to  third party claims actions or proceedings, potentially past the amount I'm being paid for. Moreover, this seems to indicate that I will have unlimited liability as, while there is a termination clause, there is no limit of liability clause.
So  to wrap up, which interpretation of the clause is more accurate to the meaning of the clause? And If it matches up with my interpretation and concerns for unlimited liability, how can I alter it to better protect myself and to make it more fair?

As a contractor you have a client not an employer!

One client asked me to have a $1Million Errors and Omissions insurance policy naming them as the beneficiary. When the project was only for a few days of work, they waived the demand.

This is pretty standard verbiage in these types of contracts, and is why you need to/must have the appropriate business insurance. If you're in the USA this probably means having professional liability insurance and general liability insurance.

Giving legal advice is fraught with dangers, and very jurisdiction dependant... and worth what you pay! So, given IANAL, what follows is personal opinion, not legal advice!
Simply, the clauses state that if the company incurs any loses (eg through customer legal action) due to your performance, you (as a supplier) will pay up.
That is what professional indemnity insurance is for...
Whether you are prepared to accept such a clause is dependant on your own situation, and your own legal advice. Personally, it seems quite wide-ranging, and (if nothing else) I'd be wanting to cap the limit of liability - and make sure I'd have appropriate PII in place.
